# Which field flower are these seeds from?

Tags: identification, seeds

I found some dry old flowers in a field and lots of seeds in them. What species is it?

[image]

*Click for a full-size version of the image.*

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you realize that we have users from all over the world? If you could add *a bit more* info on where you found this, we *might* be able to help you.

Comment: I'd guess this is a Physalis variety: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physalis

Answer (score 2):

It comes from *Rhinanthus sp*. It is an annual hemi-parasitic herbaceous plants in the family Orobanchaceae. Generally it loves meadows which are not too much fertilized (which is a good thing to preserve biodiversity and water quality!). So these species are indicators of rather "good" environmental conditions!